# Append new list every iteration of the for loop

Tags: python, list, append

I want to somehow append to a new list every time I enter a `for` loop. Currently I have:

```
A=[ ] 
B = [ ]
C = [ ]

For i in range (1, 4):
   if i == 1:
        A.append(x)
   if i == 2:
        B.append(x)
   ...
```

and so on. I am looking for an easier way to do this, as it feels so hard-coded.

Comment: Sounds like a job for dictionary.

Comment: It should be `A.append(i)` correct?  Where does `x` come from?

Comment: This may be a dumb question. Why not skip the for loop and add the items directly? Ex. `A = [x]; B = [x]; C = [x]`

Comment: The reason I am using for loops is because this is just The first column,  this for-loop is in another for loop. The resultat should basically be: A=[1,4,7...] B=[2,5,8...] where the numbers are indexes from another list, X, that contain all these numbers

Comment: What is it that you're really trying to accomplish--for what purpose?  This is the sort of question that seems to assume a certain solution is the correct one, without first describing what is trying to be accomplished.  Might also be a good question for codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a list of lists:

```
>>> A=[ ]
>>> B = [ ]
>>> C = [ ]
>>> allLists =[A,B,C]
>>> X=range(10,20)
>>> for i,j in enumerate(X):
...   allLists[i%len(allLists)].append(j)
...
>>> A,B,C
([10, 13, 16, 19], [11, 14, 17], [12, 15, 18])
```

Another way is to use slicing:

```
>>> def chunk(l,n):
...  result=[]
...  for i in range(n):
...    result.append(l[i::n])
...  return result
...
>>> A,B,C=chunk(X,3)
>>> A,B,C
([10, 13, 16, 19], [11, 14, 17], [12, 15, 18])
>>> A,B,C,D=chunk(X,4)
>>> A,B,C,D
([10, 14, 18], [11, 15, 19], [12, 16], [13, 17])
```

Comment: The reason I am using for loops is because this is just The first column,  this for-loop is in another for loop. The resultat should basically be: A=[1,4,7...] B=[2,5,8...] where the numbers are indexes from another list, X, that contain all these numbers

Comment: @snickinicki I have updated, but you should update your question with what you really want to do.